# Trying to create a soulbound token. Keep getting two errors

Tags: solidity, erc-721, error, inheritance, function-override

I'm trying to create a soulbound (non-transferable NFT) token on Solidity. Here is my code so far.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.17 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract SoulboundToken is ERC721 {
   uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;

   constructor() ERC721("SoulboundToken", "SBT") {
       _tokenIdCounter = 0;
   }

   function mint(address to) public {
       _mint(to, _tokenIdCounter);
       _tokenIdCounter++;
   }

   function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override {
       require(from == to, "Soulbound tokens cannot be transferred");
       super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
   }
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
TypeError: Function has override specified but does not override anything.
  --> Soulbound token.sol:18:86:
   |
18 |    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override {
   |                                                                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
TypeError: Member "_beforeTokenTransfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract super SoulboundToken).
  --> Soulbound token.sol:20:8:
   |
20 |        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried fixing these two errors. Nothing works. Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using version 5 of OZ contracts.

In version 5 they have removed the `_beforeTokenTransfer` and `_afterTokenTransfer` functions. And introduced a new single function, [_update](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/78d5708340b5ad1aed18c1e97e6d089b7c6f07fd/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L188).

[image]

Now you need to override this function only, and include whatever logic is needed.

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice this. The code seems more cleaner now.

Answer (score 0):

If OpenZeppelin Version V4.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.17 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract SoulboundToken is ERC721 {
    uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("SoulboundToken", "SBT") {
        _tokenIdCounter = 0;
    }

    function mint(address to) public {
        _mint(to, _tokenIdCounter);
        _tokenIdCounter++;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 firstTokenId,
        uint256 batchSize
    ) internal override {
        if (from != address(0)) {
            require(from == to, "Soulbound tokens cannot be transferred");
        }

        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, firstTokenId, batchSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the _update from ERC721. When a transfer is attempted, the if statement checks if the token has an existing owner (from != address(0) ) and is not being sent to a zero address (to != address(0) ). If both conditions are met, it implies a valid transfer attempt. This is version >5.0.0

```
function _update(address to, uint256 tokenId, address auth)
    internal
    override(ERC721, ERC721Pausable)
    returns (address)
{
    address from = _ownerOf(tokenId);
    if (from != address(0) && to != address(0)) {
        revert("Soulbound: Transfer failed");
    }

    return super._update(to, tokenId, auth);
}
```